# NAB Transact hosted payment page doesn't trigger reply_link_url

Tags: php, callback, payment-gateway

I'm using hosted payment page, here system redirects to nab transact page for payment and displays receipt page after transaction approved.
I set the return_link_url and reply_link_url in input hidden variables as below.

```
<form action="https://demo.transact.nab.com.au/live/hpp/payment" method="post" id="payment">
<input type="hidden" name="vendor_name" value="XXXXXXX" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="payment_alert" value="xx@xx.com.au" />
<input type="hidden" name="print_zero_qty" value="false">
<input type="hidden" name="return_link_text" value="Click Here to Return to the Home Page">
<input type="hidden" name="return_link_url" value="http://www.mysite.com.au/index.php?route=payment/nabtrans/callback&order_id=51216" />
<input type="hidden" name="reply_link_url" value="http://www.mysite.com.au/index.php?route=payment/nabtrans/callback&order_id=51216" />
<input type="hidden" name="Pay for Order number 51216" value="22" />
<input type="hidden" name="payment_reference" value="51216" />
<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="XXX XX" />
<input type="hidden" name="information_fields" value="Name">
```

The problem is the reply_link_url is not getting triggered automatically at the time payment receipt page is displayed to customer as mentioned in guide.

I tried with appropriate cgi handler which does executes if called. So, I used them in the reply link url, but still the link doesn't triggered automatically.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_link_url" value="http://www.mysite.com.au/cgi-bin/handler.cgi?orderid=51217" />
<input type="hidden" name="reply_link_url" value="http://www.mysite.com.au/cgi-bin/handler.cgi?orderid=51217" />
```

I have to click on return link on payment receipt page to come back to website. The reply_link_url never triggered automatically after the receipt page displayed in 15 sec timeout. I made sure to use http in reply link url to make it listening on port 80. The CGI script executes if I run it in browser.

---

#### Solved

I used two different url's for reply_link_url and return_link_url.
They are

```
 <input type="hidden" name="return_link_url" value="http://www.mysite.com.au/index.php?route=payment/nabtrans/replyback&order_id=51216" />
 <input type="hidden" name="reply_link_url" value="http://www.mysite.com.au/index.php?route=payment/nabtrans/callback&order_id=51216" />
```

I made sure to add the code inside callback function to execute the background process after payment approves and used code for redirecting to payment success page inside replyback function. Both these functions reside in nabtrans controller. As I noticed the the reply link triggers automatically which executes the background processes to update order, but the last step of displaying the checkout/success page never bring the link from payment success page of nabtrans to the original website. Still I was happy all background tasks done. So,  I used the return link for coming back to original website. This solves the purpose completing transaction and coming back to website.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I got this solved recently. Please see the edits for details. Thanks

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Comment: @user2006054  Hi , can you please tell what if any user directly click on reply_link_url vai browser , may be then your order auto update without payment.  Thank you very much